# UIImageView disappears after rotate and move to edge

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, transform, uigesturerecognizer

I have written a custom class which offers the feature to move and rotates images.

I need to restrict the movement to the boundaries of parent view or Superview.
So, I wrote below code to restrict it.

This works fine before an image is rotated. If I try to rotate the image and then move the image to an edge, Image disappears leaving no log or traces.

Why does it disappear and how do I avoid it?

```
if(frame.origin.x < 1)
{
    frame.origin.x = 1
}
if(frame.origin.y < 1)
{
    frame.origin.y = 1
}
if(frame.maxX > superview!.frame.width)
{
    frame.origin.x = superview!.frame.width - frame.width - 1
}
if(frame.maxY > superview!.frame.height)
{
    frame.origin.y = superview!.frame.height - frame.height - 1
}
```

If I remove the above code, nothing disappears but image moves out of boundaries. So I feel something wrong in only above lines.

So help me to correctly implement this feature after rotation.

Full Movable Image Class code :

```
class movableImageView: UIImageView
{
    var CenCooVar = CGPoint()

    override init(image: UIImage!)
    {
        super.init(image: image)

        self.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let moveImage = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveImageFnc(_:)))
        let rotateImage = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateImageFnc(_:)))

        self.gestureRecognizers = [moveImage,rotateImage]
    }

    func moveImageFnc(moveImage: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if moveImage.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
        {
            CenCooVar = self.center
        }

        if moveImage.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
        {
            let moveCooVar = moveImage.translationInView(self.superview!)

            self.center = CGPoint(x: CenCooVar.x + moveCooVar.x, y: CenCooVar.y + moveCooVar.y)

            if(frame.origin.x < 1)
            {
                frame.origin.x = 1
            }
            if(frame.origin.y < 1)
            {
                frame.origin.y = 1
            }
            if(frame.maxX > superview!.frame.width)
            {
                frame.origin.x = superview!.frame.width - frame.width - 1
            }
            if(frame.maxY > superview!.frame.height)
            {
                frame.origin.y = superview!.frame.height - frame.height - 1
            }
        }

        if moveImage.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
        {
            CenCooVar = self.center
        }
    }

    func rotateImageFnc(rotateImage: UIRotationGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if rotateImage.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, rotateImage.rotation)
            rotateImage.rotation = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tags go in the tags section, not in titles. Do not add "Swift" to your title. And as you're talking about an UIImageView, do not remove the "UI" part. Thanks.

Comment: Moritz is correct, the name for this class is UIImageView. You've already tagged the question with [swift], and this most likely isn't a Swift-language-focused problem, so it's best to focus on the class in question.